# Access violation writing location 0x0133585B Error

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am working on a program in C and the following function takes in three parameters and will replace a character in a string with another character.  Well most of it works just fine but i get en error when trying to execute this portion of code : str[pos] = ch;.  Error says "Access violation writing location 0x0133585B."

```
void kstrput(char *str, size_t pos, char ch)
{
    if(pos > strlen(str))
    {
        abort();
    }
    str[pos] = ch;
}
```

Portion of main:

```
char *kstr = "hello";
    int pos = 3;
    char s = '\0';
    printf("\n Enter a character ");
    scanf("%c", &s);
    kstrput(kstr,pos,s); // calling the kstrput function
    printf("\n After kstrput: %s",kstr); //printing the struct to check value of the string
```

Comment: Show the code that calls the function. You're probably passing a string literal, which is not writable.

Comment: If `pos == strlen(str)` then you overwrite the `null` terminator and `str` is no longer a valid string. Undefined behaviour from the subsequent `print` follows.

Comment: using strlen this way is almost always wrong: the caller of you function must give the length of the string as "guessing" it inside the function is very risky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"hello"` is constant (not modifiable) and might be (and probably is) stored in a read only memory.

The proper way to point to it is by using pointer of type `const char *`.
What you need to do in your case is to define array of `char` and initialize it to "hello":

```
char kstr[] = "hello";
```

Also note that in `kstrput` if `pos` is equal to `strlen(str)` then it will override the `'\0'` which indicates the end of string.
Better use:

```
if(pos >= strlen(str))
```

Answer (score 1):

> "Access violation writing location 0x0133585B."

you do

```
{
  int pos = 3;
  ...
  char *kstr = "hello";
  ...
  kstrput(kstr,pos,s); // calling the kstrput function
}

void kstrput(char *str, size_t pos, char ch)
{
   str[pos] = ch;
   ...
}
```

in `str[pos] = ch;` *pos* valuing 3 is a valid index but *str* is the string literal "hello", a string literal cannot be modified

Answer (score 0):

This line in function void kstrput(char *str, size_t pos, char ch)

```
if(pos > strlen(str))
```

should be replaced by

```
if(pos >= strlen(str))
```